# How to ContourPlot a multi input function with the response as color?

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have the multi input function y = 87.0184 - 0.119876 x1 - 28.4708 x2 - 3.47058 x3 + 0.0457349 x1 x2 + 0.0039625 x1 x3 + 1.2455 x2 x3. Ranges are {x1, 0, 100}, {x2, 2.0, 3.0}, , {x3, 20, 22}.

How can I make a ContourPlot3D, where the x, y and z axes are the x1, x2 and x3 variables and the response y value mapped as color on the surface?

Thank in advance

Comment: If I look at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html and I click on the orange Details and Options and I look for `ColorFunction` and I click on that then the first basic example includes `ColorFunction->Function[{x,y,z},Hue[z]]` Can you adapt that example for your problem

Comment: w=f[x,y,z] and the color respect to w?

Comment: `DensityPlot3D[
 87.0184 - 0.119876 x1 - 28.4708 x2 - 3.47058 x3 + 0.0457349 x1 x2 + 
  0.0039625 x1 x3 + 1.2455 x2 x3, {x1, 0, 100}, {x2, 2.0, 3.0}, {x3, 
  20, 22}, ColorFunction -> Hue, ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

y = 87.0184 - 0.119876 x1 - 28.4708 x2 - 3.47058 x3 + 
   0.0457349 x1 x2 + 0.0039625 x1 x3 + 1.2455 x2 x3;

ContourPlot3D[y, {x1, 0, 100}, {x2, 2, 3}, {x3, 20, 22},
 Contours -> Range[8.5, 16.5, 2],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x1, x2, x3}),
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic,
   LegendLabel -> Style["y", 12, Bold]]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** The label rotation below will not automatically adjust to changes in the view point and the placement is not ideal. Modifications would probably need to go back to using graphics primitives or a specialized plotting package.

```
ContourPlot3D[y, {x1, 0, 100}, {x2, 2, 3}, {x3, 20, 22},
 Contours -> Range[8.5, 16.5, 2],
 AxesLabel ->
  (Style[Rotate @@ ##, 10, Black, Bold, Italic,
      FontFamily -> "Papyrus"] & /@ {
     {"very long label 1", -0.5},
     {"very long label 2", 0.6},
     {"very long label 3", 1.7}}),
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[Automatic,
   LegendLabel -> Style["y", 12, Bold]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, axis names are longs, like "Temperature °C" and "Depth of Observed cut (mm)" . Is there a way to write then parallel to the axis and specify the font name name and size?

Comment: Is it possible to draw the planes at certains values or set the number of planes?

Comment: `Contours -> Range[8.5, 16.5, 2]` specified the values for the contours. Change it however you wish. See docs for `ContourPlot3D`

Answer (score 0):

Another useful possibility is to use "SliceContourPlot3D":

d = 2;
SliceContourPlot3D[
f[x1, x2, x3], {x1, -d, d}, {x2, -d, d}, {x3, -d, d},
PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]

[image]